# Approximation of ratio between logarithms

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

I have issues showing the following fact:
For $x \in (0, 1/2)$, 
$$\frac{\log(2/x)}{\log(1/(1-x)} \approx \frac{1}{x}$$

I have tried with the trick of adding $1-1$ in the log, and using Taylor expansion of $\log(1-x) \approx x$, but I get:

$\frac{1+\frac{2}{x}}{1+\frac{1}{1-x}}= (\frac{x+2}{x})(\frac{1-x}{2-x})=\frac{-x^2+x+2}{-x^2+2x}$, which is not what I expect.

Are there any other tricks to get what I think is correct?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerator $log(2/x)=log(2/(x-2+2))=log(1/(x/2-1+1))=-log(1+(x/2-1)\approx 1-x/2$

Denominator $log(1/(1-x))=-log(1-x)\approx x$

Ratio $\approx(1-x/2)/x$.

Major problem:  for $x$ near $0$, numerator appprox. is not very good.